# Rest EJB Project not deploying on Wildfly 8.0

Tags: rest, jboss, ejb

I am creating Project Using Rest EJB. When I try to deploy on Jboss throws following error

am using jboss standalone for database configuration

```
12:14:06,358 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'webservice.war#webUnit'
12:14:06,359 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment webservice.war
12:14:06,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'webservice.war#webUnit'
12:14:06,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment webservice.war (runtime-name: webservice.war) in 30ms
12:14:06,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "webservice.war" (runtime-name: "webservice.war")
12:14:06,588 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for webUnit
12:14:06,616 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'webservice.war#webUnit'
12:14:06,616 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: webUnit
    ...]
12:14:06,627 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment webservice.war
12:14:06,630 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named EmployeeEJBImpl in deployment unit deployment "webservice.war" are as follows:

    java:global/webservice/EmployeeEJBImpl!com.webservice.service.EmployeeEJBIf
    java:app/webservice/EmployeeEJBImpl!com.webservice.service.EmployeeEJBIf
    java:module/EmployeeEJBImpl!com.webservice.service.EmployeeEJBIf
    java:global/webservice/EmployeeEJBImpl
    java:app/webservice/EmployeeEJBImpl
    java:module/EmployeeEJBImpl

12:14:06,650 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: webservice.war
12:14:06,653 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment webservice.war
12:14:06,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'webservice.war#webUnit'
12:14:06,659 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
12:14:06,660 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
12:14:06,663 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
12:14:06,663 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": none
12:14:06,798 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016018: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs:main. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi]
12:14:06,843 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webservice: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webservice: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:204)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:736)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:762)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:89)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addClientExceptionMapper(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1048)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1346)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1268)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registerProvider(ResteasyDeployment.java:531)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:338)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:241)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:303)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$100(ClientProxyProvider.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:52)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper.mapHttpException(org.apache.http.HttpException)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper.mapHttpException(org.apache.http.HttpException)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction.run(GetDeclaredMethodAction.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction.run(GetDeclaredMethodAction.java:22)
    ... 49 more

12:14:06,850 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webservice" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webservice: Failed to start service
    Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper.mapHttpException(org.apache.http.HttpException)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper.mapHttpException(org.apache.http.HttpException)"}}
12:14:06,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "webservice.war" with deployment "webservice.war"
12:14:06,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice.war".component.EmployeeEJBImpl.START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice.war".component."org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."webservice.war#webUnit" (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webservice: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webservice: Failed to start service
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webservice
```

but if I remove following lines from web.xml it gets deployed

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

but on access of my url(http://localhost:8080/webservice/) throws this error

```
12:22:05,207 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (default task-3) JBAS016018: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs:main. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi]
12:22:05,247 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /webservice/: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:74) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:204) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:736) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:762) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:61) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:89) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:64) [resteasy-cdi-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2211) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addClientExceptionMapper(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1048) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1438) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1346) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1268) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registerProvider(ResteasyDeployment.java:531) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:338) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:241) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:112) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:220) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:163) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:84) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:303) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:111) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:180) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:170) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$100(ClientProxyProvider.java:45) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:56) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:52) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper.mapHttpException(org.apache.http.HttpException)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<clinit>(Unknown Source) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper.mapHttpException(org.apache.http.HttpException)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction.run(GetDeclaredMethodAction.java:39) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction.run(GetDeclaredMethodAction.java:22) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    ... 72 more
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.webservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Validationg Form -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- logger  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <!-- imp this will force deployed file name to be artifacid else in url 
        we need to provide complete file name including 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -->
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>webservice</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>html/welcome.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="webUnit">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/webDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.webservice.model.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class,hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The answer given here might be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308617/error-in-simple-resttful-web-service-implementation

Comment: I tried that too doesn't work error remains same ...

Comment: Issue resolved. I just had to add scope for my <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> depencency . <scope>provided</scope>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem resolved by changing scope as provided for dependency

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

1. compile

This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

2. provided

This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

As explained in

[Difference between maven scope compile and provided for JAR packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging)